# PHP OOP and Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am new to PHP OOP and I am having problem getting arrays back.

```
class example
{
    public $array;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->array = array();

    }

    public function do_work()
    {
        $this->array[] = 'test';
    }
}
$test = new example();
$test->do_work();
$test->array;
```

I keep getting a empty array instead of 'test'.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: new example() would create the object with the array and $test->array will technically allow you access the array but if you don't call $test->do_work(); the array will not contain anything.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to invoke do_work() in the constructor? Also, it's never a good idea to use protected keywords for variable names.

Comment: @Ansari: I disagree with both of your statements. Please do explain.

Comment: Sorry guys, I just added do_work().

Comment: @BlakeJeffery: Your code (as it is, literally copy pasted) works flawlessly. Are you sure that is your entire code?

Comment: @Truth I wrote the comment before OP updated the question. He wasn't invoking the method at all. As for the second thing - setting variable names to be the same as keywords of a language can be OK, but can lead to avoidable confusion.

Comment: @Ansari: I misunderstood the second one (was searching for `protected` all over the place!), by the first disagreement, I meant that one should not do work (oh the irony!) in the constructor, the factory (i.e. whoever instantiated the object) should be doing it instead.

Comment: Yes I could have used more precise terminology. I meant protected in the sense of reserved keywords. And yes, I suppose it's better to have the instantiator call methods on the object, but sometimes you may want to just move some code away from the main constructor and call a method to run it instead right? Is this a bad design method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you never actually call the function `$test->do_work();`  The constructor just creates the empty array, and then you attempt to access the property.  It *should* be empty.

**Updates**

I see you updated your question.  If you simply `echo $test->array`, it should just print `Array`.  However, when I copy your updated code and perform a `var_dump($test->array)`, this is the output I get:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "test" }
```

Which I believe is what you are expecting.  The code that you have in your question, though, should output nothing. You are doing nothing with `$test->array`, the variable is being evaluated and then thrown away.

Comment: Note that in the original answer, OP didn't have `$test->do_work()` in his code. It's not shown due to the edit grace period.

Comment: @Blake no problem, glad we could help.

Answer (score 4):

Your last statement, `$test->array;` doesn't actually do anything. My guess is that you are using something like `echo`. Your code should output the array if you use for example `var_dump`, [see the example on codepad](http://codepad.org/sqUwUyWJ)